# Unread result found SQL, Python tkinter

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

When trying to delete anything from "eksamen" it just returns Unread result found.
the "print (data_s)" returns "('PRG1000', '2022-05-05', 'E321')", which is a row found in the database, i can make it work by using buffered=True in my cursor, but i want to do this without the use of it.

```
def slett():
    emnekode_s = emnekode.get()
    dato_s = dato.get()
    rom_s = rom.get()
    dato_s2 = str(dato_s)
    print(dato_s2)
    eksamensliste_markor = mindatabase.cursor() 
    eksamensliste_markor.execute("SELECT Eksamen.Emnekode, Eksamen.Dato, Eksamen.Romnr FROM Eksamen LEFT JOIN Eksamensresultat ON Eksamen.Emnekode = Eksamensresultat.Emnekode AND Eksamen.Dato = Eksamensresultat.Dato WHERE Eksamensresultat.Dato IS NULL ORDER BY Eksamen.Dato ASC;")    
    for row in eksamensliste_markor:
        if emnekode_s == row[0]:
            print('rød')
            if dato_s2 == str(row[1]):
                print('grønn')
                if rom_s == str(row[2]):

                    emnekode_s = str(row[0])
                    dato_s2 = str(row[1])
                    rom_s = str(row[2])

                    eksam_s = (
                        'DELETE FROM Eksamen WHERE Emnekode = %s AND Dato = %s AND Romnr = %s'
                    )

                    data_s = (emnekode_s, dato_s2, rom_s)
                    print (data_s)
                    print('Check')
                    eksamensliste_markor.execute(eksam_s,data_s)
                    mindatabase.commit()

    eksamensliste_markor.close()
```

Comment: Try changing `for row in eksamensliste_markor:` to `for row in eksamensliste_markor.fetchall():`.

Comment: oh shoot! should probably mention im not allowed to use fetchall :ss sorry!

Comment: Then try using another cursor object for the DELETE statement.

Comment: seems like that wouldnt do the trick either *grumble* weird how this wont work